# Rails devise - Facebook + Twitter +

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, oauth, devise

I'm thinking to use devise gem for a new Rails app I'm working on.
I'm a bit confused about a thing. The app will allow the user to connect to FB, Twitter and possibly other social network (Foursquare, etc..).
I know that with devise + omniauth-facebook you can allow the user to register to your site by FB user (or same applies to twitter).
I just wonder: if you allow the user to login by FB user and then you also want to connect the same user to his/her twitter account, does devise support this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check this tutorial, this explains multiple authentication with Facebook and Twitter + normal user registration process with Devise:
http://www.orhancanceylan.com/rails-twitter-and-facebook-authentications-with-omniauth-and-devise/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. You also need to disclose that it's your site.

Comment: ThiefMaster is right. If your (?) site disappears this answer will be worthless. That's why we copypasta to SO.

Comment: The site has in fact disappeared now.

Comment: It's up and it was the only blog that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this sample source code](https://github.com/mohitjain/social-login-in-rails) which integrates with all the popular social networks ie Devise + Twitter + Facebook + Linkedin + Google + Github

*Disclaimer: I wrote that application. In case you are facing any issues. Feel free to ping me on stackoverflow or open an issue on github.*